New to Ubuntu Studio - VST3 Plugins
I have discovered Ubuntu Studio in my search to avoid the re-tooling necessary for Windows 11. I am happily surprised. I have used Ableton and Reaper. I see Reaper will transfer to Linux. Will my VST3 Plugins move over as well?
I have begun contributing via PayPal monthly to Ubuntu Studio. I also belong to PLAP, Produce Like a Pro - Warren Huart's audio production Academy. I hope to produce via Ardour and represent this platform there. Thank you all for your help in advance. -Pete Z. aka DeepFrequency
